# GreaseMonkey script to rewrite image links

Tags: javascript, firefox, replace, greasemonkey, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace image links with img src url in Greasemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703719/how-to-replace-image-links-with-img-src-url-in-greasemonkey)

I'm new to javacript and want to write a GreaseMonkey script to rewrite certain image links on a website to display the original size images instead of thumbnails.

The image links are in the forms below:

```
<div class="feed_img"><a onclick="App.scaleImg(this,'7e87e5d5tw1difluxvqlzj');" href="javascript:;"><img src="http://ww3.sinaimg.cn/thumbnail/7e87e5d5tw1difluxvqlzj.jpg" class="imgicon" vimg="1"></a></div>
```

What I want to do is to replace

```
http://*/thumbnail/*.jpg
```

to

```
http://*/large/*.jpg
```

Could anyone give me a lead?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Give it a go. This is a great exercise if you're new to JavaScript, and you'll learn a lot more if you piece a solution together yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to traverse all of the `<img>` tags and just replace `thumbnail` with `large` in their `src` attribute:

```
// This fetches all of the <img> tags and stores them in "tags".
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

// This loops over all of the <img> tags.
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {

  // This replaces the src attribute of the tag with the modified one
  tags[i].src = tags[i].src.replace('thumbnail', 'large');
}
```

Hopefully this code works. I'm using a basic `replace()`, so if you'd like to try regex, I think it should work too.

Comment: Looks good to me, I don;'t see any benefit to using regex in this case.

Comment: This will nuke all images on the page!  I imagine the OP only wants to tamper with the "payload" images.

Comment: @Brock: You could add some checks to sift out unwanted links. I'm not writing *all* the code for the OP...

Comment: Why not?  More-correct code requires just a change to the first line.  I'd do it myself but the question is a duplicate and the OP apparently didn't do even a cursory search.

Comment: What do you mean by "more correct code"?

Comment: Code that changes links only within `div.feed_img`.  Also, Use the @Brock prefix or I won't see an alert about comments addressed to me (here).

Comment: I‘ve tried a couple of solutions in similar questions  and neither of them have any effect on the webpage. So I filed a new question.

Comment: I do without the `@Blender` prefix. There's a delay. I'll add in iteration over classes too... Isn't the OP supposed to be doing this?

Comment: @WTF, can you elaborate a bit more? Did you get any errors? Did you modify the other scripts to your needs, or did you just copy & paste them blindly? We can't really read minds (yet).

Comment: This code has no effect on the image links either.The site requires an account to view. Maybe providing the source of the whole page might help?

Comment: I get a error in the error console:tags.length is not a function

Comment: @Blender, `"I do without the @Blender prefix"` -- that's because it's your answer.  Does not apply to me since (1) there is more than one other commenter, (2) it's not my answer. ...    Forgot to elaborate in earlier comment...  Use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll) in the first line. ...   Finally there was an error in this answer's code that caused the OP's error.  I fixed that for you.

Comment: @Blender, The problem turned out to be the UserscriptLoader.uc.js I was using. I installed scriptish instead and the code works perfectly!Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW, is there a way to rewrite the links before firefox downloads the thumbnail files? I can see the thumbnails show first and replaced in about a second. It's not a big deal but I'm curious about how to do it.

Comment: That is because you're running the script too late. It's running when the page loads, but you need to run it when the DOM is ready.

Comment: @Blender, I added DOMContentLoaded event to the script and it doesn't change anything..I read somewhere that GM script runs at DOMContentLoaded by default, is it true? Could it be because that although the script runs immediately when DOM is ready, but it doesn't abort the action of downloading external resouces? The replacement process is really short and starts a bit of earlier than using "load" event.